# Using Django-genereted SQL tables in another project

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

There is a Django-powered site. There is a need to create a stand-alone service (written in another language & platform) which should be able to perform all  the CRUD operations on the SQL database that's used by the Django site.

Obviously, new tables won't be available to the Django site as models, but what I'm interested in is what happens with records that were inserted/deleted/updated from the outside.

It seems absolutely legit for me. However, as I have a limited experience of web & Django development, it would be better to know this for sure.

- Is it considered a normal practice?
- Is it possible to break any "Django-side things" this way? Like, migrations or whatever else it could be?
- Are there any things I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it considered a normal practice?

To me seems a bad practice. Really bad practice. Django owns that data and makes sense that only the owning application can access that data.

> Is it possible to break any "Django-side things" this way? Like, migrations or whatever else it could be?

If you don't change the table structures, and don't mess with Django admin tables, you won't break the django side of things

I would suggest making the Django application a service. Whichever application needs data managed by Django can request it, and Django is responsible for handling that data. Take a look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ and if you don't know about REST or SOA take a look at those.

Comment: Well, the reason why I was thinking about direct access to the database is performance. In fact, the other application's primary goal is to be an API that should handle a significant amount of requests (i.e. thousand requests per second and more).